# Include unmatched records when joining with non merge-joinable and non hash-joinable conditions

Tags: postgresql

If I have data representing points and areas:

```
CREATE TABLE test_areas AS (
SELECT id area_id, ST_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x,y), 32632), 2) geom
FROM ( VALUES (1,2,2),(2,4,6) ) s(id,x,y) );

CREATE TABLE test_points AS (
SELECT id point_id, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x,y), 32632) geom
FROM ( VALUES (0,1,1),(1,1,3),(2,1,5),(3,3,6),(4,5,7),(5,7,8) ) s(id,x,y) );
```

To apply the id of the containing area for each point I would write a query:

```
SELECT area_id, point_id
FROM test_points p JOIN test_areas a ON ST_Intersects(p.geom, a.geom)
```

To include points that are not within any area (`point_id = 2, 5`) under a separate category (e.g. 0) I would normally use `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `COALESCE` but `ST_Intersects` does not support this.

I can do this in with a workaround:

```
WITH c AS (
SELECT area_id, point_id
FROM test_points p JOIN test_areas a ON ST_Intersects(p.geom, a.geom)
)
SELECT 0 area_id, point_id
FROM ( SELECT point_id FROM test_points EXCEPT SELECT point_id FROM c) s
UNION
SELECT * FROM c
```

Is there a better way to include unmatched records without using `FULL OUTER`?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a better solution:

```
SELECT COALESCE(area_id, 0) area_id, point_id
FROM test_points
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT area_id, point_id
  FROM test_points p JOIN test_areas a ON ST_Intersects(p.geom, a.geom)
) s USING (point_id)
```

You join the points again with the result, though I'm not sure about the performance.

If you only need the area and point ids (no other value columns from points) you can shorten the query to:

```
SELECT COALESCE(area_id, 0) area_id, point_id
FROM test_points p1
JOIN test_areas a ON ST_Intersects(p1.geom, a.geom)
FULL OUTER JOIN test_points USING (point_id);
```