# Full Outer Join on ST_Intersects gives error but worked sometimes

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, postgis, outer-join

I am getting the intermittent error:
`FULL OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.`
BigQuery ran it for a few hours yesterday but is now giving me this error again.

I confirmed using the Personal History that the query that succeeded yesterday gives this error today.
Either way this is the query that's giving the error and I am not able to come up with another query that gives this same result. I've seen [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642441/include-unmatched-records-when-joining-with-non-merge-joinable-and-non-hash-join) but my geometries don't have unique ids that I'm aware of.

```
SELECT * FROM 
`segments`  AS s
FULL OUTER JOIN `zones` AS z
ON ST_Intersects(s.linestring, z.geog)
```

Comment: have you tried using `LEFT OUTER JOIN ... UNION ALL ... RIGHT OUTER JOIN` instead `FULL OUTER APPLY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar problem in query with `FULL OUTER JOIN` and spatial condition (and yes, query can also indeed be completed successfully), but now I still don't fully understand the reasons.

While as a "quick" fix, try using instead FULL OUTER JOIN joins with UNION ALL:

```
SELECT * FROM segments s
LEFT OUTER JOIN zones z
ON ST_Intersects(s.linestring, z.geog)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM segments s
LEFT OUTER JOIN zones z
ON ST_Intersects(s.linestring, z.geog)
```